# Certain column in "current item" in workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm creating a list which will later act as a template. For this list, there will be a reusable workflow that will send me a mail of a certain column is edited.

So the workflow would be something like; `If Current Item:CertainColumn equals Yes -> email`.

However, I can't seem to find that specific column under "Current Item". But I can see another column that's on the list. But not this one that I would like. As if I've forgotten to add that column to something that would make it appear in the Current Item list.

I'm using SPD 2013 and the workflow is built for 2010 if that helps.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the column is not set to be hidden.

Close SPD and try opening it again.

Comment: Not set to hidden, but the ones that's shown are. Forgot to mention that the ones showing are the standard ones for a task list, like "created by" and "task name". Restarting SPD didn't change anything :( If I scroll down on "data source" I can see my lists there, but since this is gonna be a template I need it to be the "Current item". And on the lists and I can see the columns under "field from source". But not under "Current item".

Comment: Ok reusable workflows are attached to a particular content types and not custom list. That is why you are not able to see those fields

Comment: But the content type that the list is assigned to have these columns, I've added them. I'm missing something here

Comment: You should open the Content Types gallery.. Create a new Content Type there...which inherits from Tasks.. and add those columns there (as site columns)... now go back to your Tasks List and attach that content type..

Comment: Found it :) When you edit the workflow you have this "Association columns" icon. Pretty big icon, missed it haha :)

Answer (score 0):

When editing the workflow there is an icon "Association column" on the top ribbon.